# Distance between two allocations and the Shapley-Folkman lemma

Tags: supply-and-demand

I have two allocations $\omega_1, \omega_2$ with the following values for the decision variables:

1. $\omega_1$: demand side: $x_1 = 1$; supply side: $y_1 = 5, y_2 = 3$
2. $\omega_2$: demand side: $x_1 = 1$; supply side: $y_1 = 4, y_2 = 4$.

I want to calculate the distance between $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$. Is the difference 0, since the total supply and demand quantities are identical in both allocations, or $\sqrt{(5-4)^2 + (3-4)^2} = \sqrt{2}$?

I want to apply the Shapley-Folkman lemma ([https://econweb.ucsd.edu/~rstarr/SFarticle.pdf](https://econweb.ucsd.edu/%7Erstarr/SFarticle.pdf)) and check if the distance between these two allocation is smaller than a specific constant.

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: If you view the allocations as points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and take their distance to be the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), then you have correctly calculated the distance as $\sqrt{2}$. I doubt the Shapley-Folkman is of much help here.